# How is implementing FOC on SVPWM switching algorithm?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, pmsm, vector-control

I have that running SVPWM algortihm with no error. I tried to implement FOC algorithm that switching metod. But I failed. I measure phase currents (Ia , Ib , Ic) when low side switching time. And calculating
`Iα=Ia  , Iβ=(1/√3)*(2Ib+Ia)` clarke transformation and then `Id=Iαcos(θ)+Iβsin(θ) , Iq=Iβcos(θ)−Iαsin(θ)` calculating park transformation. This θ value is electrical angle that I got it from hall sensor information between 0 to 360 degree? Or am I wrong ? I set reference Iq and Id value . Then I used pid regulator. I used `Vα=Vdcos(θ)−Vqsin(θ) , Vβ=Vqcos(θ)+Vdsin(θ)` inverse park transformation . I think this θ value same with first park transformation θ value. Is there any wrong thing my progress ? Or it can be problem using Vα , Vβ in SVPWM algorithm?

Comment: You have to know how the θ you get from the Hall sensors relates to the electrical angle of the motor.

Comment: Hall sensors and FOC is a no go. The angle is the rotor position angle.